# how to bind dataset one column values to textboxes dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

In `DataSet` I have 4 columns. In button click I have to display the entire one column values in textboxes 
dynamically. Like when we see `FB` comments all comments will be displayed in `textboxes` dynamically.
please help me.

I am fresher to SW .>

```
ds = l2.messageshow(); //drag the data into ds

Convert.ToInt32(ds);
int linenum = 0;
foreach (int x in ds)
{   
}
```

when I am using the above code I get the following error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type dataset

Comment: i mean in this way can i used it or not.i dont know how to used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like the below Code

```
ds=l2.messageshow();//drag the data into ds
Convert.ToInt32(ds);
int linenum = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) //Change Here
{   
     //Your code
}
```

You cant convert the whole `DataSet` into `int` to have the line Number use `DataRow` for getting the data of the `DataSet` line by line

**Edit:**

If you want only one column from `DataSet` to dispaly it in `textbox` use the below code

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
  {
    txtBox.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
  }
```

I am assuming your `DataSet` having only one Table and one `Row`

---

If you want to display entire column in `textboxes` dynamically you may create Textboxes dynamically and assign DataSet Values to it try the below code,

```
ds=l2.messageshow();//drag the data into ds

int linenum = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

TextBox[] textbox= new TextBox[linenum]; //Modified line

for (int i = 0; i < linenum; i++)
{
  textbox[i] = new TextBox();
  textbox[i].ID = "textbox[" + i + "]";
  PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox[i]);
  textbox[i].Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```

Keep in mind Dynamic Controls will be lost after Postback to retain it follow this Example [how-to-retain-values-of-dynamically](http://ruchirac.blogspot.ca/2012/07/how-to-retain-values-of-dynamically.html) or This Example [Dynamic Controls in Placeholder lossed after postback](http://forums.asp.net/post/1667338.aspx)

Comment: but here i want to display the only one column values and how to bind it to textboxes dynamically

Comment: sir,i want to display entire one column like Messages

1)Hi
2)How are u
3)iam in Chennai
 like this i want to display entire column in textboxes dynamically

Comment: thanks for ur responding. but it shows this error bhayya                 Error 11 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox[]' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Comment: Modify the `textbox=new Textbox[linenum];` as `TextBox[] textbox= new TextBox[linenum];`

Comment: Thankyou very much bayya.its working.thankyou very much becoz i had askes so many times but you dont stopped ur replys.thakyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your requirements is you want to display entire column rows in textboxes dynamically.

Let's assume that you don't know how many rows your dataset would have. So what you do to create textboxes dynamically equal to the number of your dataset rows?

Let we have a user control containing one TextBox.

Steps To Implement:

- Count the rows of dataset.
- Bind the control to a panel or container in a loop having iteration count equal to the dataset rows.
- In each iteration grab the column value and assign it to the TextBox before docking the control inside      the control container.

Code:

```
 foreach(var row in DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
  UserControl objCtrl = new UserControl();
  objCtrl.Controls["Your TextBox Id Here"].Text = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
  Panel.Controls.Add(objCtrl);
 }
```

If Problem Persists in provided solution then please comment.